# c# Passing type to a child class

Tags: c#, generics

I'm writing a RESTFUL client library, and part of the return object type depends on the parameters of the request.

For instance, the client has a method called ExecuteCommand, that returns a response object which looks like this:

```
public class MyResponse
{
   public MyResult Result{ get; set; }
   public MyResponseHeader ResponseHeader { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the MyResult class:

```
public class MyResult
{
   public object[] DocumentList{ get; set; }
   public int NumRecords{ get; set; }
   public int Start{ get; set; }
}
```

What I'd like to do is pass a "Document Type" to the ExecuteCommand method, and have it return the MyResponse object with the MyResult object having the IDocument be the type passed in.

Something to this effect:
    `MyResponse response = MyClient.ExecuteCommand<MyDocument>(request);`

In this instance, what I'd like to have returned is the MyResult with a DocumentList of type MyDocument.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use generics on your classes:

```
public class MyResponse<T>
{
   public MyResult<T> Result{ get; set; }
   public MyResponseHeader ResponseHeader { get; set; }
}

public class MyResult<T>
{
   public T[] DocumentList{ get; set; }
   public int NumRecords{ get; set; }
   public int Start{ get; set; }
}
```

Then you can have your `ExecuteCommand` create your `MyResponse` using its own `T` (in this case `MyDocument`), and using var will make it even easier and more readable:

```
var response = MyClient.ExecuteCommand<MyDocument>(request);
```

Comment: This is actually how I coded it, I just wasn't sure about passing the type down the line.  Thanks, Drew